fine code coverage Tool is generating bin and debug folders in visual studio 2022
Installed product versions
Visual Studio: [2022 Professional]
fine code coverage version: [ 1.1.223]
After running tests fine code coverage is generating bin folders and project specific debug folders in the solution explorer

Steps to recreate
run the tests on right click of solution explorer
Current behavior:
All bin and debug folders are getting created in the solution explorer
Expected behavior:
only report should be generated without creating any bin or debug folders
